# Need help ending a program with a do while loop

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I am creating a wordle project, where the word is set to "tyler". The user's guess is saved as a string, as is the wordle word, "tyler". Both the strings are saved as characters in an array, then the program checks whether each character in the arrays match.
My code is here:

```
// Nelson's work
import java.util.Scanner;

class FinalProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Nelson's work
        int counter = 0;
        do {
            String word = "tyler";
            System.out.println("Press enter to begin");
            // Saves userInput as a string
            String userInput = input.nextLine();
            while (userInput.length() != 5) {
                System.out.println("Enter a 5 letter word: ");
                userInput = input.nextLine();
                counter++;
            }
            // End of Nelson's work
            // Tyler's work
            // Creates an array of length equal to string length
            char[] ch = new char[userInput.length()];

            // For loop to put characters into array
            for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
                ch[i] = userInput.charAt(i);
            }
            // 'For each' loop to print each element of the array
            for (char c : ch) {
                System.out.println(c);
            }
            // Creates an array of the size of the wordle word
            char[] wordle = new char[word.length()];

            System.out.println(" ");
            // Characters of string wordle word which is 'tyler' are in an array
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                wordle[i] = word.charAt(i);
                // System.out.println(wordle[i]);
                if (wordle[i] == ch[i]) {
                    System.out.println("Letter " + ch[i] + " is correct");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Letter " + ch[i] + " is not correct");
                }
            }
            System.out.println(" ");

        } while (counter <= 5);

        System.out.println("You lost!");

        // End of Tyler's work

    }

}
```

I am trying to make a do while loop that reprompts the user for a word, giving the user 5 tries, and the program would end if A) the user has had all 5 tries, or B) the user gets the word right. Please help with the loop, or if there is additional code I should try.

I tried to put the variables inside the dowhile loop, but one of the variables is from a scanner (it is user input), but I need that inside the do while loop so it reprompts the user while the counter is less than or equal to 5.

Comment: You haven't actually said what's wrong, but one immediate issue i see is that you increment counter inside the user prompt loop. So if a user tries to enter a single letter more than 5 times and then 5 letters, they lose after one 'guess'

Comment: Don't put inside the loop what doesn't need to be, i.e. `String word = "tyler";` of ` System.out.println("Press enter to begin");` etc. You should also end the loop when the user found the word, either by checking for the win condition in the `while(...)` as well or checking inside the body and using `break` to end the loop. Finally, before printing "You lost!" check the user still had a try - you might need to rearrange this to make it easier, e.g. rename `counter` to `attempts` or so, initialize it with 5, decrement on each attempt and change the condition to `attempts > 0`.